# Keeping the order when unstacking in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame where the index is a `DatetimeIndex`

**Applying the value_counts() for each month:**

```
NameCount = df.resample("M")["Name"].value_counts()

Date          Name

2019-12-31    Tom                   200
              Alle                  185
              Will                  93
              Jeff                  90
              Jerry                 68

2020-03-31    Alle                  629
              Jame                  385
              Will                  233
              Jerry                 113
              Tom                   99
```

**Unstacking the result rearranges the `Name` alphabetically:**

```
NameCount.unstack().rename(lambda  x: x.strftime("%b %Y"))
```

Is there a way I could keep the order from `value_counts` where it was arranged in a `descending order`

Comment: Is possible add some data sample?

Comment: One moment! Will do.

Comment: Can you check now?

Comment: Thank you, also what is expected output?

Comment: I will like to keep the order from the value_counts()

Comment: I ask because seems not possible.

Comment: I think if need different order for each row...

Answer (score 2):

From pandas v2.1, there is an option `.unstack(..., sort=False)` that turns off sorting in unstack.

---

Here is a solution for previous versions of pandas.

This is a general unstack I came up with. It keeps the order as it was for both the index and the columns.

However, if the index is not consistent about the order(!) like in your example, we can't do anything about that. We can only order it by the apparent order of appearance in the index.

```py
def unstack_keep_order(df, level):
    new_index = df.index.droplevel(level).unique()
    new_cols = df.index.get_level_values(level).unique()
    return df.unstack(level).reindex(new_index).reindex(new_cols, level=-1, axis='columns')
```

Code to test it out with an interesting enough case

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['B', 'A'], ['z', 'x', 'y'], ['b', 'a']])
index = index.insert(-1, ('B', 'w', 'b'))

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=np.arange(index.size * 2).reshape((-1, 2)), columns=[("1", "A"), ("2", "B")]).convert_dtypes()
```

[image: df unstack vs unstack_keep_order]

Answer (score 1):

If want order by unique values of second level use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
c = NameCount.index.get_level_values(1).unique()
df = NameCount.unstack().rename(lambda  x: x.strftime("%b %Y")).reindex(columns=c)

print (df)
Nam         Tom   Alle   Will  Jeff  Jerry   Jame
Date                                             
Dec 2019  200.0  185.0   93.0  90.0   68.0    NaN
Mar 2020   99.0  629.0  233.0   NaN  113.0  385.0
```